# Js function working only once

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a simple javascript photo editor, and I'm stuck on this part:

```
var opacity = document.getElementById("opacity").value;
var contrast = document.getElementById("contrast").value;
var saturate = document.getElementById("saturate").value;
var brightness = document.getElementById("brightness").value;
var color = document.getElementById("color").value;
var sepia = document.getElementById("sepia").value;

function filter() {
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + color + "deg) sepia(" + sepia + "%) brightness(" + brightness * 3 + "%) saturate(" + saturate + "%) contrast(" + contrast * 2 + "%)";
}

var filters = document.getElementsByClassName("slider");
for (i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    filters[i].addEventListener("click", filter);
}
```

This function works only once. Similar function for opacity:

```
function opacity() {
    var a = document.getElementById("opacity").value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.opacity = a / 10;
}
document.getElementById("opacity").addEventListener("change", opacity);
```

works fine. Any ideas why? I tried doing it this way:

```
/*
function contrast() {
    var b = document.getElementById("contrast").value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "contrast(" + b * 2 + "%)";
}

document.getElementById("contrast").addEventListener("change", contrast);

function saturate() {
    var c = document.getElementById("saturate").value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "saturate(" + c + "%)";
}

document.getElementById("saturate").addEventListener("change", saturate);

function brightness() {
    var d = document.getElementById("brightness").value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "brightness(" + d * 3 + "%)";
}


document.getElementById("brightness").addEventListener("change", brightness);

function color() {
    var e = document.getElementById("color").value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + e + "deg)";
}

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("change", color);

function sepia() {
    var f = document.getElementById("sepia").value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "sepia(" + c + "%)";
}

document.getElementById("sepia").addEventListener("change", sepia);
/*
```

And everything is ok, but then I'm unable to apply multiple filters. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide codepen or jsfiddle? maybe if you have a online code editor, just to view your working codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value every time you click

```
var contrast = document.getElementById("contrast");
var saturate = document.getElementById("saturate");
var brightness = document.getElementById("brightness");
var color = document.getElementById("color");
var sepia = document.getElementById("sepia");
function filter() {
    //You have to convert to number to do arithmetic
    var _brightness = ~~brightness.value;
    document.getElementById("output").style.filter = "hue-rotate(" + color.value + "deg) sepia(" + sepia.value + "%) brightness(" + _brightness * 3 + "%) saturate(" + saturate.value + "%) contrast(" + contrast.value * 2 + "%)";
}
```

*and so on*